# How do I stop UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment error?

Tags: python

I keep getting this error:

`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'result' referenced before assignment`

Here is the code:

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums = list[int], target = int) -> list[int]:
        for i in nums:
            for j in nums:
                if i == j:
                    pass
                else:
                    if i + j == target:
                        i_in = nums.index(i)
                        j_in = nums.index(j)
                        result = i_in, j_in
            break
        return result

nums = [2, 7, 11, 15]
target = 9

sol = Solution

sol.twoSum(None, nums, target)
```

I tried declaring the `result` variable globally or at the start with a value of `0`

```
def twoSum(self, nums = list[int], target = int) -> list[int]:
        result = 0
```

But then I just get this error:

```
TypeError: 0 is not valid value for the expected return type integer[]
    raise TypeError(str(ret) + " is not valid value for the expected return type integer[]");
Line 42 in _driver (Solution.py)
    _driver()
Line 49 in <module> (Solution.py)
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
Line 42 in serialize_list (./python3/__serializer__.py)
Line 53 in _serialize (./python3/__serializer__.py)
    out = ser._serialize(ret, 'integer[]')
Line 40 in _driver (Solution.py)
```

EDIT:

I've now tried:

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums = list[int], target = int) -> list[int]:
        for i in nums:
            for j in nums:
                if i == j:
                    result = list[int]
                else:
                    if i + j == target:
                        i_in = int(nums.index(i))
                        j_in = int(nums.index(j))
                        result = i_in, j_in
            break
        return result
```

And i get the same error but `TypeError: list[int]` instead. Why? the class type is `list[int]` and that's what ive given it. I've tried just `list` too. It says the expected return type is `integer[]`

Comment: few bugs: `sol = Solution` --> `sol = Solution()` |  `twoSum` type hint says it will return list of int - but its not. Fixt it and go on

Comment: You defined the return type of `twoSum` to be a list of integers. `0` is not a list of integers; it's a single integer.

Comment: Your only other assignment to `result` involves a *third* type, a 2-tuple of  integers. You need to decide what type `result` should have and stick to it.

Comment: Whatever error you are seeing is a result of whatever code uses your class, not something Python itself is doing. The driver appears to be using the static type hints for runtime type checking.

Comment: I got no error with the new edit. Side remark: to avoid to pass a ```None``` the the method use the ```classmethod``` decorator ot "empty" constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your approach of initializing `result` is theoretically correct, but the type has to be correct as well. `result = 0` defines `result` as an `integer` but as you specify the return type as `list[int]` you should initialize `result` accordingly.

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums = list[int], target = int) -> list[int]:
        result = []
        for i in nums:
            for j in nums:
                if i == j:
                    pass
                else:
                    if i + j == target:
                        i_in = nums.index(i)
                        j_in = nums.index(j)
                        result.append(i_in)
                        result.append(j_in)
            break
        return result

nums = [2, 7, 11, 15]
target = 9

sol = Solution

sol.twoSum(None, nums, target)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `break` statement in your code is placed such that the outer `for` loop only runs the first iteration and `result` never gets defined. I would suggest adding tabs behind it so that it gets to the right place.

And by the way, you seem to be using bad syntax in `list[int]`. It should actually be `[int()]` or even `[0]`. But if there's a reason you're doing this that I don't know, then okay. The main issue is in the `break` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your error araise for example with

```
nums = [2, 7, 11, 15]
target = 11
```

but that is a consequence of the fact the result is not defined in the `i == j` condition so your function will return a value which is not defined.

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums = list[int], target = int) -> list[int]:
        for i in nums:
            for j in nums:
                if i == j:
                    result = 'Hallo, fix a default value!'

                else:
                    if i + j == target:
                        i_in = nums.index(i)
                        j_in = nums.index(j)
                        result = i_in, j_in
            break
        return result
```

Comment: I've made an edit to show me trying that too but getting an error